# Separate a Pandas dataframe based on contents of time column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe of which one column is datetime. The data spans over a month and is sorted on time in ascending order. Now I want to separate out weekend and weekday data, this is my code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
data.head()

              Time                     A       B      C
0    2018-12-26 14:04:05.519842       276     120     76
1    2018-12-26 14:05:05.730416       52      52      12
2    2018-12-26 14:07:07.791897       52      52      12
3    2018-12-26 14:08:05.373717       200     210     40
4    2018-12-26 14:10:05.861872       40      106     0
```

## Introduce a new column called weekday

```
data['weekday'] = data['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())

weekday_data = data[data['weekday'] < 5 ].drop(columns=['weekday'])
weekend_data = data[data['weekday'] >= 5 ].drop(columns=['weekday'])
```

So `weekday_data` contains all data from Mon-Fri, and `weekend_data` contains all data in Sat and Sun.

Now I want weekend data to contain all data from Fri 5pm onwards (Not all of friday's data) to Sun 23:59:00.
Note : The 2 output dataframes (`weekday_data` and `weekend_data`) must be time sorted as was my original data.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2019-03-29 11:00:00', periods=30, freq='3H')
data = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng, 'a': range(len(rng))})  
print (data)
                  Time   a
0  2019-03-29 11:00:00   0
1  2019-03-29 14:00:00   1
2  2019-03-29 17:00:00   2
3  2019-03-29 20:00:00   3
4  2019-03-29 23:00:00   4
5  2019-03-30 02:00:00   5
6  2019-03-30 05:00:00   6
7  2019-03-30 08:00:00   7
8  2019-03-30 11:00:00   8
9  2019-03-30 14:00:00   9
10 2019-03-30 17:00:00  10
11 2019-03-30 20:00:00  11
12 2019-03-30 23:00:00  12
13 2019-03-31 02:00:00  13
14 2019-03-31 05:00:00  14
15 2019-03-31 08:00:00  15
16 2019-03-31 11:00:00  16
17 2019-03-31 14:00:00  17
18 2019-03-31 17:00:00  18
19 2019-03-31 20:00:00  19
20 2019-03-31 23:00:00  20
21 2019-04-01 02:00:00  21
22 2019-04-01 05:00:00  22
23 2019-04-01 08:00:00  23
24 2019-04-01 11:00:00  24
25 2019-04-01 14:00:00  25
26 2019-04-01 17:00:00  26
27 2019-04-01 20:00:00  27
28 2019-04-01 23:00:00  28
29 2019-04-02 02:00:00  29
```

New column is not necessary, create mask by [`Series.dt.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) compared with `>5` joined by `|` for bitwise `OR` with another mask - filtered only `Fridays` with [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)s - chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m1 = data['Time'].dt.weekday >= 5
m2 = (data['Time'].dt.weekday == 4) & (data['Time'].dt.hour >= 17)
m = m1 | m2

weekend_data = data[m]    
weekday_data = data[~m]
```

---

```
print (weekend_data)
                  Time   a
2  2019-03-29 17:00:00   2
3  2019-03-29 20:00:00   3
4  2019-03-29 23:00:00   4
5  2019-03-30 02:00:00   5
6  2019-03-30 05:00:00   6
7  2019-03-30 08:00:00   7
8  2019-03-30 11:00:00   8
9  2019-03-30 14:00:00   9
10 2019-03-30 17:00:00  10
11 2019-03-30 20:00:00  11
12 2019-03-30 23:00:00  12
13 2019-03-31 02:00:00  13
14 2019-03-31 05:00:00  14
15 2019-03-31 08:00:00  15
16 2019-03-31 11:00:00  16
17 2019-03-31 14:00:00  17
18 2019-03-31 17:00:00  18
19 2019-03-31 20:00:00  19
20 2019-03-31 23:00:00  20
```

---

```
print (weekday_data)
                  Time   a
0  2019-03-29 11:00:00   0
1  2019-03-29 14:00:00   1
21 2019-04-01 02:00:00  21
22 2019-04-01 05:00:00  22
23 2019-04-01 08:00:00  23
24 2019-04-01 11:00:00  24
25 2019-04-01 14:00:00  25
26 2019-04-01 17:00:00  26
27 2019-04-01 20:00:00  27
28 2019-04-01 23:00:00  28
29 2019-04-02 02:00:00  29
```

Comment: I am reading my data from a csv file, and then converting it to a datetime object.  pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])  and then running your code. But I get this error :    AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @BidishaDas - Sure, in my answer `data = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng, 'a': range(len(rng))}) ` is only for sample data, be free change it by `data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', parse_dates=['Time'])`